# True or False (Matrix, Linear Algebra I)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let A, B be non-square matrices. AB and BA are defined. If AB is an Identity Matrix, then BA is also an Identity Matrix.
True or False?

Comment: Did you try any examples? Say, small ones with $2 \times 1$ and $1 \times 2$ matrices?

Comment: As I understood, if AB is an identity matrix then B=A^(-1). But A, B are non-square and as far as I know identity matrices and invertible matrices can only be square.

Comment: Have you thought about what it means for the product $AB$ to be the identity matrix? Since A and B are not square can the same be said about A and B if A and B are square as if they are not? If not, can we say something about A and B for AB,but not for BA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the following example with $\;B\;$ a $\;2\times 1\;$ matrix and $\;A\;$ a $\;1\times 2\;$ one:

$$AB=(1\;0)\binom10=(1)\;\;,\;\;BA=\binom10 (1\;0)=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$$